# Kubernetes pipeline fails: the resource you were accessing could not be found

Tags: kubernetes, github, digital-ocean, cicd

Someone set up Kubernetes on Digital Ocean for me, with a Github CI/CD pipeline. It has worked for several months, but now suddenly the pipeline is consistently failing.

See the error below. Any idea what is going wrong?
As I said, nothing about the pipeline has changed compared to when it did work.

The part of the pipeline I think is relevant:

```
- name: Install doctl
  uses: digitalocean/action-doctl@v2
  with:
    token: ${{ secrets.DIGITALOCEAN_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
- name: Build container image
  run: docker build -t registry.digitalocean.com/***/***:$(echo $GITHUB_SHA | head -c7) .
...
- name: Save DigitalOcean kubeconfig with short-lived credentials
  run: doctl kubernetes cluster kubeconfig save --expiry-seconds 600 k8s-***-production
```

[image: DO Kubernetes pipeline]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out a Digital Ocean service was down, causing the reported issue...